# Show changed job title for employer using modern cv

Tags: moderncv

I need help altering this resume.

How can I add a second job title 'Junior Research Assistant' for the dates 'Feb 2018 - Feb 2019' in the line directly below Research Assistant?
[image]

Reproducible code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[center]{banking} % <=====================================
\moderncvcolor{black}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75, 
% top=2cm, bottom=2cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}
\linespread{1.1}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{1111 Nowhere Street, Apt 111}{Nowhere, NW}{11111}
\phone[mobile]{(100)-111-1111}
\email{johndoe@johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/]{john-doe}  % <===================
\social[github][github.com/johndoe]{john-doe}  % <=================

\title{Business Analysis | Data Analysis | Project Management | Information Systems} % <============================================
%\moderncvhead[center]{3}% <====================================== already called by banking
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% 
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% 
  }%
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}% <===============================================
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    {\centering\textbf{\@title}\\[2em]}% <==============================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother

\raggedbottom % <=======================================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle


\begin{center}
\section{Professional Experience}
\end{center}
\cventry{Mar 2019--Present}{Research Assistant}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere}{}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\newline{}%
Key Contributions:%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

{%\newline{}% <=========================================================




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution, but changing the \cventry works.
I split your current \cventry into two. The first one will be:

```
\cventry{Mar 2019--Present}{Research Assistant}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere}{}{}
```

and the second one:

```
\cventry{Feb 2018 - Feb 2019}{Junior Research Assistant'}{}{}{}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\newline{}%
Key Contributions:%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}
```

Output:
[image]